# JDBI Inserting NULL into bit column causes java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Data truncation: Data too long for column

Tags: java, mysql, jdbi

When running a batch update query using jdbi library with a query similar to below

`@SqlBatch("INSERT INTO <table> (<columns>) VALUES (<columnsBind>)" + " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE <updateString>;")`

I get a `java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Data truncation: Data too long for column bit_column` error for a column of type bit(1).

I'm attempting to insert a NULL value into this.

I've confirmed that the column is nullable.

In debugging I'm able to see that the binding for the named value is of type `ObjectArgument` rather than `NullArgument` though it's not a problem for other entries which can handle the null just fine.

I tried to replace the `ObjectArgument` with `NullArgument` but that leads to a `java.io.NotSerializableException`

Is this something anyone has run into before?

EDITED: With an edited version of the ClientPreparedStatement object that is generated, I've renamed the columns and changed the ones with actual values to others of the same type. All nulls are the same, they were unquoted.

```
INSERT INTO table (not_bit_column_null,bit_column,not_bit_column_null,varchar_column,varchar_column,not_bit_column_null,varchar_column,not_bit_column_null,not_bit_column_null,not_bit_column_null,varchar_column,varchar_column,varchar_column,not_bit_column_null,not_bit_column_null,varchar_column,not_bit_column_null,id,not_bit_column_null) VALUES (null,null,null,'text','text',null,'text',null,null,null,null,'text','text',null,null,'text',null,'22',null) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE not_bit_column_null = null,
bit_column = null,
not_bit_column_null = null,
varchar_column = 'text',
varchar_column = 'text',
not_bit_column_null = null,
varchar_column = 'text',
not_bit_column_null = null,
not_bit_column_null = null,
not_bit_column_null = null,
not_bit_column_null = null,
varchar_column = 'text',
varchar_column = 'text',
not_bit_column_null = null,
not_bit_column_null = null,
varchar_column = 'text',
not_bit_column_null = null,
id = '22',
not_bit_column_null = null;
```

Comment: is `null` quoted in your statement? If so, it's a string, not a value of null.  Speaking of, can you log the actual sql being performed, with values?

Comment: @billjamesdev I've updated the post with a query example. The `null` is not quoted.